# Prerequisites for Sullivan's 1970 notes

Tags: self-learning, geometric-topology, advice

What are the mathematical prerequisites to start reading Sullivan's MIT lecture notes of 1970: [Geometric Topology: Localization, Periodicity, and Galois Symmetry](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/books/gtop.pdf)? I have already learnt some algebra (the content of Atiyah-Macdonald plus some more), and algebraic topology (the first three chapters of Hatcher).